# Receiving non-ascii characters from BLE advertisment data

Tags: ios, non-ascii-characters

I developed an app in iOS which detects beacons in range (using CoreBluetooth), but whatever encoding I may use, I only get the characters which have a corresponding ASCII translation (so 0xF0 is not received, but anything from 0 to 0x0F is received). Does anyone encountered this problem before?

Comment: Can you share a little of your code? Specifically, what APIs are you using to receive the data?

Comment: Also a hex dump of the received data and what you expect.

Comment: I am using didDiscoverPeripheral to detect the beacon. The bytes I am checking is the advertismentData parameter, specifically the CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey part. I expect 0xF3 but I don't get anything (I receive less bytes than expected) @dpassage

Comment: Can you update the question with that information, ideally also including some actual code?